# Return/invoke the NotFoundHandler in slim framework

Tags: php, slim

Im trying to redirect to the 404 page. Laravel has an option to to this with `abort(404)`.

Currently I'm doing

`return $response->withStatus(404)->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')->write('Page not found');`

But this doesn't redirect to my "normal" or the app´s standard 404 page.

I have read the [docs](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/handlers/not-found.html), but how to I invoke the notFoundHandler from wherever in the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can throw `NotFoundException`.

```
throw new \Slim\Exception\NotFoundException($request, $response);
```

Answer (score 0):

My not found handler

```html
<?php

$app = new \Slim\App();

$container = $app->getContainer();

$container['notFoundHandler'] = function ($c) {
    return function (\Slim\Http\Request $request, \Slim\Http\Response $response) use ($c) {
        $view = $c->get('view');
        $view->render($response, '404.php');
        return $response;
    };
};
```